# Excel add same prefix to two values within one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

not sure if this can even be done, Google search has not been too helpful (mainly due to the fact its just returning how to add a prefix)

Problem:

I have one column in Excel with two comma separated values - for arguments sake, "Bill, Ted" in A1 and I'd like to add a prefix to BOTH of the names, lets just say the word "excellent"

What I have so far looks like this and yields the correct result but only for the first value, so is there a way I can define it to attach the prefix to the next value?

=CONCATENATE("excellent",A1) - "excellentBill, Ted"

So my desired result would be:

"excellentBill, excellentTed"

I'm sure its pretty straighforward but I've been trying different approaches with CONCATENATE and SUBSTITUTE and just can't seem to get the desired result. I was wondering if you can prepend a LEN FUNCTION but wondered if there is a simpler approach?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like `="excellent "&(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",", excellent "))`?

Comment: Thank you. This gets me very close to the desired output, however I realised I made a mistake on the output it should have read "excellentBill,excellentTed" (no spaces) and what I get is "excellentBill,excellent Ted"

This is what I'm using ="excellent"&(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",excellent")) not sure where the extra space is coming from.

Comment: you have a space after the comma in your input so therefore there is a space on the output. Instead of just the comma replace ", " where you'd include the space.

Comment: Thank you I see what you mean now. Works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I'm finding the delimiter in the cell then building around that.

`="Excellent" & left(A1, Find(",",A1))& "Excellent" & right(A1, len(A1) -Find(",",A1))`

`=Concat("Excellent",left(A1, Find(",",A1)),"Excellent",right(A1,len(A1) - Find(",",A1)))`

Comment: Thank you. This also worked but I have further different length values within those columns and this seemed to slice some of them - I should have mentioned that it would need to be global for lengths but I did get the desired result purely from this formula.

Comment: @phownz I added a `Len()` function to it so it should be able to handle global lengths. In the future, have your examples mirror the way your data is structured otherwise the solution might be overfitted to your example, not your working file.

Comment: Undestood Mark, makes total sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes it did!

Comment: @phownz, Awesome! Would you mind marking it as answered so we can close this out? (I'll remove this cringe-worthy request afterwards)